# What needs to be inside of __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, package, init

As a somewhat novice starting to create some python modules, I have to ask what needs to be inside `__init__.py` to make the modules or program better and feel more professional?

I know that `__init__.py` doesn't really need anything inside it to work but looking at some professionally made python modules and packages, there seems to be a lot inside it?

**Can you please tell me what needs to be there?** Or is it just optional to actually put anything in there other than a docstring explaining what the module does.

**Not the '__init__' function, but the file `__init__.py`**

Comment: I recommend looking at a good python tutorial on classes.

Comment: can you recommend me some? @COLDSPEED

Comment: The documentation seems like a good place to begin.